# `git log --topo-order`の`topo`はどのような意味でしょうか？

Tags: git

## 環境

```
$ git --version
git version 2.33.0
```

## 質問

`git log`コマンドは、デフォルトではコミット順で表示する`--topo-order`オプションが有効になっています。

```
       --topo-order
           Show no parents before all of its children are shown, and avoid showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed.

           For example, in a commit history like this:

                   ---1----2----4----7
                       \              \
                        3----5----6----8---

           where the numbers denote the order of commit timestamps, git rev-list and friends with --date-order show the commits in the timestamp order: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.

           With --topo-order, they would show 8 6 5 3 7 4 2 1 (or 8 7 4 2 6 5 3 1); some older commits are shown before newer ones in order to avoid showing the commits from two parallel development track
           mixed together.
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

`--topo-order`オプションの`topo`はどのような意味でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[トポロジカルソート](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%88%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88)という言葉で使われる topological と同じ意味でしょう。つまり `--topo-order` とは、トポロジカルソートで並べたときの順番、という意味です。

（ここでいうトポロジーとは[ネットワーク・トポロジー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%88%E3%83%9D%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%83%BC)という言葉で使われるような意味合いで、それぞれのコミットの親子関係のネットワーク構造のことを指しているといって[差し支えないはずです](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/30659/42623)。）

Answer (score 1):

言葉の意味までは私も詳しくないので解説できませんが、恐らく **topological** の略かと思われます。

[How can I sort a set of git commit IDs in topological order? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22714371)

[Topological order (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_order)